# How to make confirmation box on another page after clicking a link, work?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Good Day!

I'd like to ask something. I have a link named "delete" at the index file. Now, I want to confirm from a user before doing the delete operation. However, I'd like to put the script for confirmation to the delete file. I've tried multiple ways, yet it's useless. But it can delete actually, my problem exactly is that, the confirmation box does not prompt. Kinda' stock in here. Please help.

Heres my code at index.php (link to delete):

```
`<p><strong>Country: </strong> <?php echo $country['countries'];?> &nbsp | 
&nbsp <a href="editcountry.php?id=<?php echo $country['id']; ?>">Edit</a> | 
<a href="deletecountry.php?id=<?php echo $country['id']; ?>" 
class="confirmation">Delete</a></p>`
```

And here's my delete.php file:

```
`<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';
$id = $_GET['id']; ?>

<script>
    function confirmationDelete(){
    var conf = confirm('Are you sure want to delete this record?');
        if(conf==true){
            <?php
                $sql = "DELETE countries FROM countries WHERE id=$id";
                if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) { ?>
                    alert("Record Deleted!");
                <?php }
                else { ?>
                    alert("Error Deleting Record!");
                <?php } ?>
        }
   return conf;
    }
</script>`
```

Comment: Why do you want the confirmation on another page? The normal thing is to confirm before leaving the current page. Anyway, putting a bit of PHP inside a JS if block isn't going to work the way you want: the PHP executes on the server *before* the browser even sees the JS.

Comment: You might have ticked the `Do not show this message again?` before. Or you can use a modal instead.

Comment: It's actually a kind of a task for me. And I should have to make it work. I can delete the record yet the confirmation box doesn't show.

Comment: But putting the confirmation box within the page where the link of delete is placed is working. It's just when I put it to the delete file, it only deletes record without a prompt.

Comment: Yes, because PHP executes in the server, *before* sending the response to the browser. JS (including confirmation boxes) executes in the browser.  So if you put the confirmation on a second page then the delete will need two separate PHP requests, the first to get the second page that displays the confirmation, and then another one to actually do the deletion.

Comment: Therefore, there's no way I can make it work, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

in

```html
<a href="deletecountry.php?id=1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" class="confirmation">Delete</a>
```

then in your deletecountry.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'dbconnect.php';
$id = $_GET['id']; ?>
$sql = "DELETE countries FROM countries WHERE id=$id";
if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Successfully Deleted';
}
else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Error Deleting';
}
// redirect to somewhereelse.php
```

then in your somewhereelse.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))
{
    echo '<script>alert("'. $_SESSION['msg'] .'")</script>';
    session_unset('msg');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a onclick='javascript:confirmationDelete($(this));return false;' href="delete.php?id=1">Delete</a>

    and create javascript function

    function confirmationDelete(anchor)
    {
      var conf = confirm('Are you sure want to delete this record?');
       if(conf)
          window.location=anchor.attr("href");
    }
                or
<a href="delete.php?id=1" onClick=\"javascript:return confirm('are you sure you want to delete this?');\">delete</a>
```